# Compatibility Mode Only Works On Shortcut

Tags: windows-xp, compatibility

I was having an issue getting an old piece of software to install on a Windows XP VM and changing the compatibility mode settings of the executable didn't do anything. While discussing my issue with a friend, he suggested making a shortcut and setting the compatibility settings on that.

Much to my surprise, it worked. He claimed that it's a long-standing bug where you can set the compatibility settings of a .exe, but they are just ignored.

Upon reflecting on trying to set compatibility settings, I've never had any success when changing it, so maybe my friend is right. Does anyone else have any similar experiences or confirm if this is true or not?